# Mocking dependency initialized in constructor

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, apache-kafka

I want to mock the dependency initialized in constructor, in my case I want to mock Kafka producer so that I can mock the sending of message over kafka, my code looks like below:

```
private Producer<String, String> producer;

private int messageTimeOut;
private String topicName;

@Autowired
public classConstructor(@Value("${bootstrap.servers}") String bootstrapServers,
        @Value("${topic.name}") String topicName, @Value("${message.send.timeout}") int messageTimeOut) {
    this.messageTimeOut = messageTimeOut;
    this.topicName = topicName;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
    props.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put("acks", "all");
    producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how this can be achieved.

Comment: Change it so the KafkaProducer is a parameter?

Comment: I agree that can be done, but I do not want to change the class structure.

Comment: Just follow Vooks first advice. Depending on the underlying framework, it might also be possible to use some framework/annotation thingy to put that producer into your class under test. In genera, you want to watch https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79 ... gives you a pretty good idea how to write testable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to mock the object created by the constructor. Ideally when you create a class, you should not instantiate the class you want to mock.
Anyway there are several workarounds to achive this.

1. Pass the KafkaProducer as a parameter in constructor.
2. Add a setKafkaProducer method to use for only unit test, and set the mock object into the class.
3. Use Reflection to set the private field 
   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/Setprivatefieldvalue.htm

Comment: Accepting this answer because it talks about cleaner approach i.e. to pass the kafkaProducer as constructor argument.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use PowerMock. It allows to return a custom object on instantiation. Something like this:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TargetClass.class})
public class Test {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(TargetClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(/* instance with you target constructor arguments */);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: everbody could be using PowerMock. But nobody who hasn't really really pressing issues (like: no alternatives) should actually use it in reality. Because in reality, PowerMock tends to create many more problems than it is actually solving.